# How can I return a directories files/folders without the directory path included?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, io, directory

I am trying to extract a list of files within a folder and am currently using:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtbxNewFolder.Text);
```

But that returns things like "C:\Users\Dahlia\Desktop\New Folder\jerry.txt". Is there a way to return only "jerry.txt", or do I need to do some sort of split on the array strings?

I am also trying to return a list of folders within a directory and am currently using:

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(txtbxOldFolder.Text);
```

But that returns things like "C:\Users\Dahlia\Desktop\New Folder\folder1". Is there a way to return only "folder1", or do I need to do some sort of split on the array strings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using LINQ you can get a list of just the files:

```
Directory.GetFiles(txtbxNewFolder.Text).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Though rather than `GetFiles` I'd probably use:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtbxNewFolder.Text).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
```

It isn't as simple to get the directory name, but this should work (untested):

```
Directory.GetDirectories(txtbxOldFolder.Text)
    .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name);
```

Similarly, there is a:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(txtbxOldFolder.Text)
    .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name);
```

Comment: The solutions you listed worked, however I did have to add .ToArray() to the end of each to get it to populate into the array.

string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(txtbxOldFolder.Text)
    .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToArray(); 

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtbxNewFolder.Text)
                          .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
                          .ToArray();

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) and LINQ

e.g.:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtbxNewFolder.Text)
                          .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(s))
                          .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the FileInfo and DirectoryInfo classes.

You can do:

```
foreach (String file in files) {
    var fi = new FileInfo(file);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(fi.Name);
}
```

Similar for DirectoryInfo.